# Failed to get canonical path when updating grub

Tags: grub, pop-os

So, I had this issue where my PC doesn't start the NVME by default and doesn't have an option to select it in the BIOS as a boot option, but it also has a SATA SSD and the NVME slot and to boot Linux I would hit F12 and select the NVME boot option from there. Otherwise, it would boot straight to Windows which is on the SATA SSD. This behavior is odd considering it's an Alienware X51 R3 and is on the latest BIOS, but that information is just for context.

To fix this, I tried moving the Linux bootloader (I use Pop OS 22.04) to the SATA SSD but since there wasn't enough space on the boot partition I ended up resizing it and everything went well. Once I moved the bootloader, I couldn't start Linux and then tried boot-repair through a Live CD, but would consistently get an "NVRAM is locked" message.
However, I managed to boot Linux by installing rEFInd using Windows, although now when I try to update my system it fails with this grub error:

```
Need to get 0 B/840 kB of archives.
After this operation, 14.8 MB disk space will be freed.
(Reading database ... 570790 files and directories currently installed.)
Removing linux-image-unsigned-6.3.2-060302-generic (6.3.2-060302.202305111150) .../etc/kernel/postrm.d/initramfs-tools:
update-initramfs: Deleting /boot/initrd.img-6.3.2-060302-generic
/etc/kernel/postrm.d/zz-update-grub:
Sourcing file `/etc/default/grub'
Sourcing file `/etc/default/grub.d/init-select.cfg'
Generating grub configuration file ...
/usr/sbin/grub-probe: error: failed to get canonical path of `/boot/grub/unicode.pf2GRUB_DISABLE_OS_PROBER=false'.
No path or device is specified.
Usage: grub-probe [OPTION...] [OPTION]... [PATH|DEVICE]
Try 'grub-probe --help' or 'grub-probe --usage' for more information.
run-parts: /etc/kernel/postrm.d/zz-update-grub exited with return code 64
dpkg: error processing package linux-image-unsigned-6.3.2-060302-generic (--remove):
 installed linux-image-unsigned-6.3.2-060302-generic package post-removal script subprocess returned error exit status 1
dpkg: too many errors, stopping
Errors were encountered while processing:
 linux-image-unsigned-6.3.2-060302-generic
Processing was halted because there were too many errors.
```

What does this even mean, and how do I fix it?

Comment: Can you post your `/etc/default/grub` file?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> /usr/sbin/grub-probe: error: failed to get canonical path of `/boot/grub/unicode.pf2GRUB_DISABLE_OS_PROBER=false'.
> No path or device is specified.

It looks suspiciously like two unrelated lines of your grub configuration files, `/etc/default/grub` or `/etc/default/grub.d` have been merged into one line.

Check the output of `grep -f -R '/boot/grub/unicode.pf2GRUB_DISABLE_OS_PROBER=false' /etc/default`.

And if there's a match, add a new line between `/boot/grub/unicode.pf2` and `GRUB_DISABLE_OS_PROBER=false` in the grub configuration files `/etc/default/grub` or `/etc/default/grub.d`.